# Push notifications with Parse, Testflight and Xcode 6 doesn't work

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform, testflight

I have an app in iOS working with Parse push notifications and is working with my developer device and with the test users in Testflight.
After test my app with Xcode 6, iOS7 and no changes, the push notifications works correctly, but doesn't work through Testflight.
Anyone with the same problem or an idea about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a provisional profile of production, because testflight works at production level.
I tested and is working fine.

I hope help u.